# Ormlite use with JSF/Glassfish/Eclipse

Tags: jsf, glassfish, noclassdeffounderror, ormlite

I am trying to use ormlite for my JSF application.

- Eclipse 3.7
- Ormlite 4.42
- JSF2.0 spec (in eclipse, glassfish)

I have added library that holds ormlite jar files i.e. core and jdbc.

My Model Class is configured as;

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "account")
public class Account {

@DatabaseField(id = true)
private String name;
@DatabaseField
private String password;

public Account() {
}
{...getters and setters...}
```

My questions are;

1. Model classes are supposed to be POJOs - is it OK to use it with annotations of ormlite?
2. Although libraries are added successfully in Eclipse, but when I try to run - it generates an error as below - is there some additional configuration required in web.xml or faces-config.xml? Since ormlite is perfectly working in jsp/servlet applications just by adding libraries jar files to the classpath.

`javax.faces.FacesException: #{register.submit}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/j256/ormlite/support/ConnectionSource`

Comment: Well. For (2) I figured out - its just a stupid inconsistency that I worked out by putting ormlite jars in java/jre/lib and ext folders. For (1), its working perfectly - So, unless there is not a bad practice associated (that other experts may comment on), it should be OK to use Ormlite this way, I believe.

Comment: For (2), you **don't** have to do that, just put the jars in your project classpath or in the `lib/ext` folder of your web application server (tomcat, jboss, glassfish...). Otherwise, you're making that only your JVM (the one in your JRE path) could use ORMLite libraries and you won't be able to export the project to other pcs or environments.